# How do I change an existing path to a binary so that it points to a newly installed updated version?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a binary that can be executed with command "run-binary" (not the actual name) and determined that it is executing per the following path:

```
john@johns-PC:~$ which run-binary
/home/john/.local/bin/run-binary
```

I have downloaded and unpacked an updated version of run-binary.  2 questions:

1. Per "best practices," where should I put the new, unpacked
   run-binary?
2. How do I update /home/john/.local/bin/run-binary so that
   "run-binary" executes from the newly installed location after doing #1 above?

Comment: Question 1 is  the answer to question 2 ...

Comment: Historically, general practice was to have the two binaries side-by-side on the system only long enough to test that the new really does what you want. Then you overwrite the old.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but if you create an alias in ~/.bashrc and have that to run your preferred path to run-binary that will take precedence over the PATH .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names of executable files are search for in the folders that are listed in your PATH setting, and in that order.

```
/home/vanadium/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

An executable installed in `.local/bin` will thus take precedence over executables with the same name placed in the other folders listed.

*1. Per "best practices," where should I put the new, unpacked run-binary?*

Definitely keep the one you want to use in `.local/bin/`. If you want to use the same command to launch it, then remame the previous version (e.g. `.local/bin/run-binary-versionnumber`) or move it to another folder, or, better, see next point.

*2. How do I update /home/john/.local/bin/run-binary so that "run-binary" executes from the newly installed location after doing #1 above?*

If you want to keep previous versions of your executable around, good practice is to place each version in its dedicated folder, or perhaps, if it is a single executable, in the `.local/bin` folder but with a distinct name, e.g `run-binary-versionnumber`. Then, you can create a symbolic link in `.local/bin` that is named how you typically want to run it, e.g. `run-binary`.

That way, the version of your choice will be started when you run `run-binary`. You still can easily run other versions by giving the specific name `run-binary-versionnumber`.

You can create symbolic links with the file manager, or with the command

```
ln -s ~/.local/bin/run-binary-versionnumber ~/.local/bin/run-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be handled with the update-alternatives command.

I recommend checking out the man page for it.  There you'll find the syntax for installing, listing, removing, selecting a preferred version of the binary programs to execute.

An example of the --list subcommand is

```
    $ update-alternatives --list java
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Detailed documentation can be found in

```
    man update-alternatives
```